# Flask "for" loop to retrieve images from the associated tables (category and product tables) -SQLalchemy

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Am trying to get the corresponging images of the products in the db, but i get the the error: TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects. The problem is on this snippet:

```html
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='uploads/' + product.image_path) }}"/>
```

```
<div class="well">
  {% for product in category_name.products %}
    <h3>
      <a href="{{ url_for('product', id=product.id) }}">{{ product.category_name }}</a>
      <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='uploads/' + product.image_path) }}"/>
      <small>$ {{ product.price }}</small>
      <small>{{product.product_name}}</small>
      <small>{{product.weight}}kg</small>
    </h3>
    {% endfor %}
```

What Am i doing wrong? If i call single product images in the database without the "for" loop, it works just fine.

Comment: Are you sure this is right? `{% for product in category_name.products %}` Should it not be `{% for product in products %}`?

Comment: in my views, i have a statatement - category_name = Category.query.get_or_404(id) - i want to get products on that specific category id thats why am using category_name.products

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I found where the problem is...there was a column in the db where the image_path was NULL, so when loop went through this row with an empty column, 'product.image_path' brought back None, hence the 'str' and 'NoneType' error.

Comment: You can answer and accept your own question if you like.

Answer (score 0):

I found where the problem was...there was a column in the db where the image_path was NULL, so when loop went through this row with an empty column, 'product.image_path' brought back None, hence the 'str' and 'NoneType' error.